Every 2nd boot Windows fails to create Pagefile on second drive
I don't have sufficient space on C:, so I manually configured an alternative location [J:]. with a size of 18GB; however, upon a reboot it may work, but sometimes the Pagefile is not created on J:. When this occurs, clicking Set within Virtual Memory results in a warning that a reboot is required, and after the reboot, it works until it fails again

Currently there's 48GB of free space on J: and I don't understand why Windows can't stably enable this Pagefile location   

$ wmic pagefile list /format:list

  AllocatedBaseSize = 64
  CurrentUsage      = 63
  Description       = C:\pagefile.sys
  InstallDate       = 20240708112216.834072+180
  Name              = C:\pagefile.sys
  PeakUsage         = 63
  Status            =
  TempPageFile      = FALSE

$ dir J:

  Volume in drive J is basin2022
  Volume Serial Number is 3622-413B

    Directory of J:\

      18/01/2022  17:32    <DIR>          vm
      06/08/2022  09:10    <DIR>          DriveFS
      04/06/2024  23:24    <DIR>          .deleteme
      06/07/2024  19:20    <DIR>          D
                    0 File(s)              0 bytes
                    4 Dir(s)  49,328,291,840 bytes free




Just a tip: this isn't a "swapfile". It's a "page file" or "paging file". Using the correct term is key to getting good results. Windows also has a swapfile nowadays, for UWP applications. It's very different.

More an overarching question: how large is the drive C: resides on and how large is C:? Unless it's a small SSD 120GB or less, there are more efficient ways to go about this, like moving user data directories [Documents, Downloads, etc.] to a partition other than C:, which is always the recommended way to configure Windows since it separates the OS from the user data and makes backing up and restoring the OS partition far more efficient and convenient. To move user data directories within %UserProfile%, Folder: Properties → Tab: Location → partition other than C: → OK

I am left wondering what events are being recorded.  Windows does not just fail to create a page file without itself complaining through an event.

As @JW0914 implied, there are three files used to serialize RAM: pagefile.sys, swapfile.sys and hiberfile.sys, and Windows may not work as expected if one is moved entirely from the OS drive. There can be additional pagefile.sys, but C:\ still needs one. Clean up the C:\ drive, even WinSxS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder?view=windows-11), move Documents, Music, Pictures and/or Videos to another drive, or get a larger main drive.

@JoepvanSteen No I didn't have PagefileOnOsVolume entry. J: is a partition on same SSD. Sometimes there's the message dialog "windows created a temporary paging file" and a 16Mb pagefile.sys is created on C:, sometimes there's no dialog and a 2Gb pagefile.sys is created on C:. Finally, setting both min and max size to same value didn't help.
